# How to query entities from unrelated tables in one batch

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I would like to query to different Tables, say apples and cars, which have no relationship so that active record goes only once to the database.

**Example in pseudocode:**

```
var q1 = new Query("select * form apple");
var q2 = new Query("select * from car");

var batchQuery = new BatchQuery(q1,q2);
var result = BatchQuery.Execute();  //only one trip to the database

var apples = result[0] as IEnumerable<Apple>;
var cars = result[1] as IEnumerable<Car>;
```

I have tried **ActiveRecordMultiQuery**, but there all Queries need to query the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this.

It seems like you might be going a bit overboard with optimization here: does it really make a noticeable difference to your application to make 2 separate queries? I think your time might be better spent looking for [N+1 select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) queries elsewhere in your application instead.

If the cost of one extra query **is** in fact significant then you probably have an issue with the database server or the connection to it.